# make question for periodic event

Tags: grammar, verbs, terminology, time, question-mark

I like to make question about the happening of some events whether it is happened every day or every week or every month...etc

how can i make question?

this is my try:
Does this event happen every day or every week or every month?

is it right?

Comment: *"Does this event happen [regularly](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/regularly)?*" would convey the meaning you want.

Comment: thank you very much @Irene yes it is happening regularly but i don't know if it is every day or every week or...etc

Comment: Then you could ask: *"How regularly does this event happen?"*

Comment: thank you @Irene that's very kind of you :) .I will use "How regularly" for asking about regular events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How frequently does this event occur?

Comment: thank you. it is happening regularly but i don't know if it is happening every day or every week or...etc i wanted to make question to someone asking him about if this event happening every day,week,month...etc

Comment: No, user44870 is giving you the answer. _How frequently_ or _how often_ is the question you want.

Comment: thank you @ColinFine for clarification that's very kind of you :)